# Changing the kit size to iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: adobe-photoshop, iphone

I am quite new to design. I found a PSD kit for the iPhone 6 but the developer mentioned that it is in vector so i should not have any problem changing the size for the iPhone 6 Plus. The problem is in the kit they are segregated by the different views (profiles, signin, sign-up etc.). Per view there are like 5 artboards, 9 artboards etc.

So my question is how I can change the size of only one artboard?

[image]

Comment: Hi JackyBoi, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

Select the Artboard Tool (V), select the artboard you want to change the size for. Either drag the sides/corner to change the size or click on the artboard name/text (ex: Artboard 1) and type in the new size at the top under width & height.